# Why are the objects in my NSMutableArray losing their values for seemingly no reason?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I am experiencing the strangest error here, and I am hoping someone can help me through it. I am in the (slow and painful) process of converting my existing app to ARC. My app is a basic book reader app that uses FMDB to talk to the db. The conversion went fine, but I am crashing now where I am supposed to be loading up my chapter names tableView.

In my header file I make this array that holds all of my custom volume objects:

```
NSMutableArray * volumes;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * volumes;
```

Am I good so far? In the .m file I synthesize my variable, and then in viewDidLoad I fill the array up with the result of a db call:

```
FMDatabase * database = [FMDatabase databaseWithName:name];

FMResultSet * set = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM book_volumes"];
volumes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while ([set next]) {
    Volume * v = [[Volume alloc] initWithResultSet:set];
    [volumes addObject:v];
}
```

The result of this is that I have the array filled up with 7 objects. If I look at the values inside of the array in the debugger window, they are all in there, and all of the custom objects have all of their properties.

When I hit play, it goes to numberOfSectionsInTableView:, and if I look at the values of my array while in this method the first time, all of the values are still there. But when  hit play, it goes to the same method again, numberOfSectionsInTableView:. Is that right? To call numberOfSectionsInTableView: twice? If I look at the values in the array during this second call, there are still 7 objects, but I CAN'T ACCESS ANY OF THEIR VALUES. They have addresses still, but try as I might, they aren't available.

This is especially problematic when we go down to cellForRowAtIndexPath:. It crashes because it can't access the data on the objects in the volumes array.

I pretty new to ARC, so maybe I'm missing something, but is there a chance that ARC is allowing the array's objects to be released too early?

I have no clue what could be going on here. I am successfully retrieving the data from the db and into the array, and then somehow it just disappears before we get to filling the tableView.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

So it still isn't working, and it is still driving me crazy. I thought I'd attach a screenshot of when I go into the numberOfRowsInSection: method, and everything gets blown up:

[image: It doesn't make sense!]

UPDATE AGAIN:

Ok so what it ended up being was that the ARC conversion tool changed the properties of my custom object to have `__unsafe_unretained` in front of it. I wish I would have caught that earlier. I took that out and changed the property to string and the error is gone.

Thanks for everybody looking this over.

Comment: It looks like your problem is with the Volume object, not the array. Can you include some details of that?

Comment: Show what is in the initWithResultSet of the Volume class, as well as how Volume's interface is declared. Your problem is likely in there

Comment: @jrturton I figured out that was the problem right as you mentioned to look into it. I updated my post to show what happened. Feel free to answer the question for some more points :)

Comment: @oofgwen - you can answer your own question and accept it yourself after a couple of hours / days. You can get your own points (and even a badge) for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so what it ended up being was that the ARC conversion tool changed the properties of my custom object to have __unsafe_unretained in front of it. I wish I would have caught that earlier. I took that out and changed the property to strong and the error is gone.

Thanks for everybody looking this over.

Comment: Don't be afraid to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
self.volumes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
volumes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: There is no difference for synthesised setters in ARC. Instance variables are `strong` by default.

Comment: Just tried it and still no luck. The only way I can get the data is to make a call to the db for it in every delegate/data source method of the tableView which is a joke